# Is it possible to get product price from info by request?

Tags: magento2, price, bundled-product

Is it possible to get product price from info with the help of request without add to cart?

```
    {
    "product":"111",
    "selected_configurable_option":"",
    "related_product":"",
    "qty":1,
    "bundle_option":{
        "137":{
            "24":"222"
        },
        "138":{
            "74":"333"
        },
        "139":{
            "31":"444"
        },
        "140":{
            "21":"555",
            "62":"666",
            "64":"777",
            "144":"888"
        }
    },
    "bundle_option_qty":{
        "137":{
            "222":"1"
        },
        "138":{
            "333":"2"
        },
        "139":{
            "444":"1"
        },
        "140":{
            "555":"1",
            "666":"1",
            "777":"1",
            "888":"1"
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: please explain breifly

Comment: I have bundle option and its quantity which is migrated from woo commerce but the issue is the final price is not available there so. we need the final price from selected options.

Comment: which page or using event ???

Comment: In  a Vendor/Module/Block

Comment: For more details please check this field product_options in this table sales_order_item

Comment: wait let me check

Comment: this is for after generate order